# VB6: Customizable connection source/string in data environment

Tags: vb6, report, reporting

In the Data Environment, you can setup the connection via accessing the Properties of the connection.

[image]

From there, you can choose the provider, the server name, and the database (I am using SQL Server 2008, by the way).

However, I see a problem in this since the connection string cannot be altered anymore once deployed. Therefore, I set the connection string of the Data Environment Connection during log on.

```
With deMain.conn1
    .ConnectionString = connString
End With
```

where `connString` is a global variable containing the connection string that is read from a .ini file.

I ran the program and encountered the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. In the Properties window of the Data Environment Connection, you must select first the **correct** Provider and click Next.

[image]

In the Connection tab, you don't have to fill-out the fields anymore.